# throwing an exception from a Spring Boot controller

Tags: spring-boot

Spring Boot 2.0.5

Would this be considered a "bad practice" why or why not

```
  @DeleteMapping(value = "/{id}")
  public Long testDeleteContactWithException(@PathVariable Long id) throws Exception {
    return contactService.testDeleteContactWithException(id);
  }
```

within the service there is a user defined exception which bubbles up.

I did see I could do a try/catch then using a ResponseEntity set a message, status code etc. but then it is more code to do that so unless there is some reason why do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your clients may hope there are a list of  status that can help their works.

And there are a way to catch all exceptions.

```
    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity exp(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex) {
        logger.error("BaseController.exp() => Error:", ex);
        ResponseEntity responseEntity = new ResponseEntity();
        if (ex instanceof YourException) {
            responseEntity.setCode(((YourException) ex).getCode());
            responseEntity.setMsg(((YourException) ex).getMsg());
        } else {
            responseEntity.setCode(ResponseState.ERROR.getValue());
            responseEntity.setMsg(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return responseEntity;
    }
```

Comment: @ExceptionHandler .. will have to try that out.